# Cannot run ASP.NET MVC Websites on IIS7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have Windows 7 professional running IIS7.  I have installed ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and VS2008. When I run the app with Cassini it runs fine. When I create a virtual directory and run it on IIS7, the app comes up with a blank web page and no errors at all.

How do I get ASP.NET MVC projects running on IIS7?

Comment: Just a suggestion... Have you tried loading an HTML file and a normal ASP.NET page? If the other types do not load then it might be a configuration issue, otherwise you will have narrowed down to being an ASP.NET MVC issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested the problem was Skype had captured port 80 so IIS could not use that port of course.

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

I run with that configuration every day. There are a few steps you need to go through to be sure IIS 7.5 (on Win 7) is configured properly. Follow the instructions using the link below. Although they're meant for Vista / IIS 7, they still hold.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/

Let us know the outcome.

Comment: Couldn't get anything from that document to help. Also tried displaying a html page as suggested above but still blank page??